# My font isn't adjusting

Tags: fonts, diagrams

I want to write Class with subscript along the sides of these blocks. but my font messes everything. I don't want to use a package as my whole doc font is fine. Can there be a way to make font small or anything to adjust my class labeles. Here's my output:
[image]

```
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{picture}(5,5)
\multiput(0.1,0.1)(0,1){6}{\line(1,0){5}}
\multiput(0.1,0.1)(1,0){6}{\line(0,1){5}}

\put(0.5,0.5){0}
\put(1.5,0.5){0}
\put(2.5,0.5){0}
\put(3.5,0.5){0}
\put(4.5,0.5){5}


\put(0.5,1.5){0}
\put(1.5,1.5){0}
\put(2.5,1.5){0}
\put(3.5,1.5){5}
\put(4.5,1.5){0}

\put(0.5,2.5){0}
\put(1.5,2.5){0}
\put(2.5,2.5){5}
\put(3.5,2.5){0}
\put(4.5,2.5){0}

\put(0.5,3.5){0}
\put(1.5,3.5){5}
\put(2.5,3.5){0}
\put(3.5,3.5){0}
\put(4.5,3.5){0}

\put(0.5,4.5){5}
\put(1.5,4.5){0}
\put(2.5,4.5){0}
\put(3.5,4.5){0}
\put(4.5,4.5){0}

\put(-0.5,4.5){$Class_{N}$}
\put(-0.5,3.5){$Class_{M}$}
\put(-0.5,2.5){$Class_{G}$}
\put(-0.5,1.5){$Class_F$}
\put(-0.5,0.5){$Class_E$}

\put(0.5,5.5){$Class_{N}$}
\put(1.5,5.5){$Class_{M}$}
\put(2.5,5.5){$Class_{G}$}
\put(3.5,5.5){$Class_{F}$}
\put(4.5,5.5){$Class_{E}$}

\put (-1.2,1.5){\rotatebox{90}{Actual class}}
\put(2.1,6.2){Predicted Class}
\end{picture}
```

Comment: `\put(-0.5,4.5){\footnotesize $Class_{N}$}`? Please make your example compilable.

Comment: also use `$\mathit{Class}_{N}$` never use the default math font for mult-letter words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please always post compilable examples rather than just code fragments so people aren't left to piece things together by guesswork.

You can change the font size locally within the picture. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{picture}(5,5)
  \multiput(0.1,0.1)(0,1){6}{\line(1,0){5}}
  \multiput(0.1,0.1)(1,0){6}{\line(0,1){5}}

  \put(0.5,0.5){0}
  \put(1.5,0.5){0}
  \put(2.5,0.5){0}
  \put(3.5,0.5){0}
  \put(4.5,0.5){5}

  \put(0.5,1.5){0}
  \put(1.5,1.5){0}
  \put(2.5,1.5){0}
  \put(3.5,1.5){5}
  \put(4.5,1.5){0}

  \put(0.5,2.5){0}
  \put(1.5,2.5){0}
  \put(2.5,2.5){5}
  \put(3.5,2.5){0}
  \put(4.5,2.5){0}

  \put(0.5,3.5){0}
  \put(1.5,3.5){5}
  \put(2.5,3.5){0}
  \put(3.5,3.5){0}
  \put(4.5,3.5){0}

  \put(0.5,4.5){5}
  \put(1.5,4.5){0}
  \put(2.5,4.5){0}
  \put(3.5,4.5){0}
  \put(4.5,4.5){0}

  {\tiny
  \put(-0.85,4.5){$Class_{N}$}
  \put(-0.85,3.5){$Class_{M}$}
  \put(-0.85,2.5){$Class_{G}$}
  \put(-0.85,1.5){$Class_F$}
  \put(-0.85,0.5){$Class_E$}

  \put(0.15,5.5){$Class_{N}$}
  \put(1.15,5.5){$Class_{M}$}
  \put(2.15,5.5){$Class_{G}$}
  \put(3.15,5.5){$Class_{F}$}
  \put(4.15,5.5){$Class_{E}$}}

  \put (-1.2,1.5){\rotatebox{90}{Actual class}}
  \put(1.6,6.2){Predicted Class}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image: local size change for font]

However, I think your diagram would be clearer if you just used the letters as labels and didn't repeat the 'class'.

That is, something like

[image: just letters]

which gives just the same information, by emphasises the key element which varies. (They're all classes - that's common and given in the headers of the rows/columns as a whole. What matters in the row/cell designators is *which* classes.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{picture}(5,5)
  \multiput(0.1,0.1)(0,1){6}{\line(1,0){5}}
  \multiput(0.1,0.1)(1,0){6}{\line(0,1){5}}

  \put(0.5,0.5){0}
  \put(1.5,0.5){0}
  \put(2.5,0.5){0}
  \put(3.5,0.5){0}
  \put(4.5,0.5){5}

  \put(0.5,1.5){0}
  \put(1.5,1.5){0}
  \put(2.5,1.5){0}
  \put(3.5,1.5){5}
  \put(4.5,1.5){0}

  \put(0.5,2.5){0}
  \put(1.5,2.5){0}
  \put(2.5,2.5){5}
  \put(3.5,2.5){0}
  \put(4.5,2.5){0}

  \put(0.5,3.5){0}
  \put(1.5,3.5){5}
  \put(2.5,3.5){0}
  \put(3.5,3.5){0}
  \put(4.5,3.5){0}

  \put(0.5,4.5){5}
  \put(1.5,4.5){0}
  \put(2.5,4.5){0}
  \put(3.5,4.5){0}
  \put(4.5,4.5){0}


  \put(-0.5,4.5){$N$}
  \put(-0.5,3.5){$M$}
  \put(-0.5,2.5){$G$}
  \put(-0.5,1.5){$F$}
  \put(-0.5,0.5){$E$}

  \put(0.5,5.5){$N$}
  \put(1.5,5.5){$M$}
  \put(2.5,5.5){$G$}
  \put(3.5,5.5){$F$}
  \put(4.5,5.5){$E$}

  \put (-1.2,1.5){\rotatebox{90}{Actual class}}
  \put(1.6,6.2){Predicted Class}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* certainly do it, but why don't you want to use some package from this millenium?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
\begin{picture}(5,5)
\multiput(0.1,0.1)(0,1){6}{\line(1,0){5}}
\multiput(0.1,0.1)(1,0){6}{\line(0,1){5}}

\put(0.5,0.5){0}
\put(1.5,0.5){0}
\put(2.5,0.5){0}
\put(3.5,0.5){0}
\put(4.5,0.5){5}


\put(0.5,1.5){0}
\put(1.5,1.5){0}
\put(2.5,1.5){0}
\put(3.5,1.5){5}
\put(4.5,1.5){0}

\put(0.5,2.5){0}
\put(1.5,2.5){0}
\put(2.5,2.5){5}
\put(3.5,2.5){0}
\put(4.5,2.5){0}

\put(0.5,3.5){0}
\put(1.5,3.5){5}
\put(2.5,3.5){0}
\put(3.5,3.5){0}
\put(4.5,3.5){0}

\put(0.5,4.5){5}
\put(1.5,4.5){0}
\put(2.5,4.5){0}
\put(3.5,4.5){0}
\put(4.5,4.5){0}

\put(-0.5,4.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{N}$}}
\put(-0.5,3.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{M}$}}
\put(-0.5,2.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{G}$}}
\put(-0.5,1.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_F$}}
\put(-0.5,0.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_E$}}

\put(0.5,5.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{N}$}}
\put(1.5,5.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{M}$}}
\put(2.5,5.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{G}$}}
\put(3.5,5.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{F}$}}
\put(4.5,5.5){\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle \mathit{Class}_{E}$}}

\put (-1.2,1.5){\rotatebox{90}{Actual class}}
\put(2.1,6.2){Predicted Class}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I just spelled out what David Carlisle was suggesting and centered the text in an ad hoc way because I forgot the `\put` syntax.